# How do I edit the uppermost navigation bar's color in xml?

Tags: android, xml

I've looked at online tutorials, but never had the question answered on how to change this **(highlighted below)**

[image]

To a hex color value of my choosing. All android gives me is Prebuilt themes. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look for the file app / res / value / color.xml there you will find that method and you can edit the color to the one of your preference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUuBP.png)